# compilation issues with tailwind Css

Tags: html, node.js, tailwind-css, package.json, npm-scripts

so I am using Tailwind CSS to work on my current project and I am having a bit of a compilation issue.

**note:** This is just a plain HTML and CSS project with no framework.

however, I did all the installation and setup with node, and also added a build script in the package.json file that compiles my styles; below is the script:

[image]

the problem is whenever I run this script on my terminal it runs but with a warning:

[image]

though my styles still work fine there is a bug. Whenever I change styles(say from 'mt-10' to 'mt-20') and refresh the page that particular style won't be effective until I run the build script again. I feel it's because of the warning.

I hope this was comprehensive enough. I'd appreciate it if anyone can help with a solution.

Regards.

Comment: The Dems issue is rather not related to the warning. You have to run build in watch mode

Comment: Yes, I agree with above comment. You need to add `--watch` at the end of the build script so it stays running and constantly watching file changes. And add `-i` after the word `build` in your build script, to clarify that is your input file.

Answer (score 0):

I think for it to work, you need to add the `--watch` flag for it to watch for changes. And regarding the error messages you have to add the input flag and ouput flag

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

Like so.
you can also check the [tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

I hope this helps :)